# Safely removing USB 3.0 drive freezes the system - why and how to fix?

Tags: 16.04, usb, kernel, usb-drive, disk

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS amd64 with *4.4.0-140-generic* Linux kernel.

After one of recent upgrades I got new unexpected behavior - when I

- select *Safely remove drive* in Caja
- click *Power off the disk* button in GNOME Disks

for my USB 3.0 external drive - the Ubuntu system freezes without any error messages. I can loose unsaved documents and other personal data.

Why this happens? How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known problem with latest *4.4.0-139-generic*, *4.4.0-140-generic* and *4.4.0-141-generic* Linux kernels.
On launchpad it is known as [bug 1803929](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1803929) (currently confirmed by 17 users).

The temporary solution is to use 138 ( *4.4.0-138-generic* ) kernel.

So I have deleted 139, 140 and 141 kernels by:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-139-generic \
linux-image-4.4.0-140-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-140-generic \
linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic
sudo apt-get install amd64-microcode intel-microcode thermald
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and wait for 142+ kernel with the fix.

**Warning: do not upgrade kernel to *4.4.0-139-generic*, *4.4.0-140-generic* or *4.4.0-141-generic* if you need to keep your data safe on USB 3.0 external disks. Subscribe to the [bug 1803929](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1803929) and after the confirmation of the fix - install newest kernel back with `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic`** .

Comment: 141 doesn't seem to resolve the issue either.

Answer (score 2):

As for me, I went ahead and upgraded my Linux kernel to 4.13.16 for my Ubuntu 16.04 OS. This fixed the problem since my kernel was over 2 years old and about due for an upgrade.

My Configuration: Ubuntu 16.04 - amd64 architecture

Please revise accordingly with regards to your choice of kernel.

Steps:

- Execute `$dpkg --print-architecture` to view the processor's architecture.
- Go to the 4.13.16 kernel here: [kernel.ubuntu.com](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.13.16)
- Download the linux-headers-4.13.16-041316_4.13.16-041316.201711240901_all.deb located under your processor's architecture.
- Download the linux-headers-4.13.16-041316-generic_4.13.16-041316.201711240901_XXX.deb located under your processor's architecture, where XXX stands for your processor's architecture.
- Download the linux-image-4.13.16-041316-generic_4.13.16-041316.201711240901_XXX.deb located under your processor's architecture, where XXX stands for your processor's architecture.
- [Optional] Move the .deb files into a folder.
- Open a terminal, change directory to where the downloaded packages are stored, and execute `$sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to install the packages (Note: this will attempt to install any and all .deb packages in the folder. It is easier to move the downloaded packages into a separate folder to avoid this situation).
- Reboot.
- Execute `$uname -r` in a terminal to verify the kernel change.

References:

- [AskUbuntu: How to update kernel...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)
- [TecMint: How to install latest kernel...](https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/)