# TTY doesn't wait for password

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, login, tty

I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> I get the terminal which prompts for the username. When I type my username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it doesn't wait for my password (its as if I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> without entering anything). Even if I enter something, the text shown in plaintext and then it keeps on saying my password is wrong. After few times, the screen is cleared and it prompts for my username again and the same loop goes on.

Comment: Same problem here since yesterday with U18.04.1. I _think_ it's since I (was) updated from kernel 4.15.0-43 to 4.15.0-44. The GUI login works, TTY login seems to automatically hit RETURN after username is entered. `/var/log/auth.log` repeatadly shows `login[939]: pam_unix(login:auth): conversation failed`, `login[939]: pam_unix(login:auth): auth could not identify password for [pduck]`, `login[939]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/tty3' FOR 'pduck', Authentication failure`. ***Can you confirm that?*** What does `uname -r` show?

Comment: Not @pranphy but I'm seeing the same things in the auth.log. However it says "FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/tty6' FOR 'UNKNOWN', Authentication failure" despite printing my username on the "could not identify password for ..." line. It then repeats that last error several times, ending with "Error in service module" instead of "Authentication failure". uname -r outputs 4.15.0-44-generic

Comment: @PerlDuck Exactly as @RobMosher said, my kernel version is `4.15.0-44-generic` and the first error message includes the username and the other ones don't even get the username because tty never waits to get username until too many attempts (5) and resets to wait for username again.

Comment: At least, someone already reported it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/1812095

Comment: It seems to be the issue with linux kernel version 4.15.0.-44-generic. I updated to a newer kernel (4.20.5) and the issue is resolved.

Comment: Likewise -- now that this is fixed -- this did it for me: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` then reboot.

Answer (score 19):

Same TTY problem with 4.15.0-44-generic on my Ubuntu Mate 18.04

I just updated to  4.15.0-45-generic, but it still doesn't fix the problem.

Only workaround that I found is to switch back to old kernel 4.15.0-43-generic.

I put on hold and removed the new kernels:

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-*-4.15.0-4[45]-generic
sudo apt remove linux-*-4.15.0-4[45]-generic
```

NB: Of course, old kernel linux-*-4.15.0-43-generic has to be present ;)
If not, then install with:

```
sudo apt install linux-{image,headers}-4.15.0-43-generic
```

Then the system boots fine on 4.15.0-43 and tty login works, but then I had problems with my second monitor (but this, I guess, it's totally another problem).

UPDATE: I fixed the second monitor problem, in fact it was a video acceleration problem, related to missing kernel modules with the previous 4.15.0-43 kernel.
The command "inxi -G" helped, me showing that my videocard was using 'fbdev' driver (framebuffer, no gpu acceleration) and not the accelerated 'modesetting' driver.

example1 (kernel modules installed):

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile v: 4.2 Mesa 18.2.2
```

example2 (kernel modules NOT installed):

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Mobile v: 4.2 Mesa 18.2.2
```

So the correct syntax for the command above is:

```
sudo apt install linux-{image,headers,modules,modules-extra}-4.15.0-43-generic
```

Comment: I am using kernel *4.15.0-45* on two different and fully updated systems. One uses a Kubuntu 18.04.1 installation and the other uses a Xubuntu 18.04.1 installation. The issue occurs on the one running Kubuntu only. The other one accepts the password in console mode ok like nothing ever happened. How can this be explained?

Comment: Weird issue. I've my laptop running Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1 where the issue is present with 4.15.0-45/44 but not with 4.15.0-43.
But on my Virtualbox VM with Ubuntu Mate 18.04.01 and kernel 4.15.0-45, the same issue is not present.

Comment: I am using kernel 4.15.0-45 with Mint Cinnamon and I've the same issue.

Comment: I forgot to mention ... I've also using framebuffer, no gpu-acceleration. This answer is very accurate.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use another kernel in **grub boot menu** (if one is available), after booting:

Choose "**Advanced options for Ubuntu**"
In my case **4.15.0.-43** was working correctly

Just try, what is available in the list (but maybe rather not the topmost entry, thats the one, that doesnt work, and not recovery mode)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is unbelievable - today I went to this bug on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (*Xenial Xerus*) with all updates and without PPAs on physical hardware.
So the problem was with `4.4.0-142-generic` kernel. The symptoms was exactly same as in question. Getty in text console sends "<kbd>Enter</kbd>"  and does not allow me to enter my password. Shows `Login incorrect` instead.

So I removed this buggy kernel and installed 138 instead (with method similar [to USB-problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099415/66509)):

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-139-generic \
linux-image-4.4.0-140-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-140-generic \
linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic \
linux-image-4.4.0-142-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-142-generic
sudo apt-get install amd64-microcode intel-microcode thermald
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-138 linux-headers-4.4.0-138-generic
```

and rebooted afterwards. I/we need to wait for normal stable kernel.

**Warning: do not upgrade kernel to *4.4.0-142-generic* if you need console login. Subscribe to the [bug 1813873](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813873) and after the confirmation of the fix - install newest kernel back with `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic`.**

Answer (score 2):

Kernel upgrade to 4.20.0 helped.

Comment: How did you install this kernel?

Comment: yes i would like to find out how to install with Linux Mint aka Ubuntu 4.20.0?

Comment: I've installed the kernel 4.20.7 using 'Ukuu´ and everything works fine... but when I tried to use x86-energy-perf-policy I realized why I should not use 'unsupported' kernels.