# timeout between entering username en password to short to enter

Tags: server, login, console, timeout

When I try to login into my console on Ubuntu Server 18 I have to enter my complete password within a second otherwise several returns are generated and I cannot login.

How can I correct this strange behavior?

I don't have this problem when logging in thru ssh.

Comment: Does this happen on each tty?

Comment: yes all 6 and only on the console

Comment: Could this be [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113704/tty-doesnt-wait-for-password)?