# cannot input password after input username and press enter in tty1 of ubuntu 16.04

Tags: tty

The version of my Ubuntu is 16.04 LTS. After Ctrl+Alt+F1, I enter the tty1. The first thing to do is to login. But when I input my username and press the enter, I cannot input the password. And it repeatedly print login incorrect.

Comment: Does it works with root?

Comment: The main problem is that I cannot input the password for the login username in tty at all.

Comment: Sounds like another case of this kernel bug: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113704/tty-doesnt-wait-for-password

Comment: I too am facing a similar issue

Comment: Same thing here on Mint Tara...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the kernel version 4.15.0-43-generic.

Remove 4.15-0-44-generic and 4.15-0-45-generic:

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-*-4.15.0-4[45]-generic
sudo apt remove linux-*-4.15.0-4[45]-generic
```

Install 4.15.0-43-generic

```
sudo apt install linux-{image,headers,modules,modules-extra}-4.15.0-43-generic
```

Instructions copied from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113704/tty-doesnt-wait-for-password)