# Tty commands doesn't run (trying loggin loop fix)

Tags: command-line, tty

I'm trying to follow the linked solution to fix my loggin loop problem. I logged in to the tty but it doesn't respond to any command. When I type enter it just breaks the line, regardless of what I've just typed.

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

I'm not sure if it is just my lack of regular shell knowledge or some deeper issue.
Thanks!

Edit:
The tty prompt gets my login and password successfully, but everything I typed after that would behave like a long string entry (enter breaking lines).

Comment: Sounds like your `tty` settings are messed up. Type `^C^C^C` to get back to your (invisible) shell prompt, then type `stty sane`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TTY doesn't wait for password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113704/tty-doesnt-wait-for-password)