# I am not able to login. Getting "Sorry that didnt work. Please try again" error before entering password

Tags: login-screen

My system is not even letting me enter my password. As soon as i select the username to enter my password i am getting an error "That didnt work Please try again."  I tried to login to tty by pressing alt+ctrl+f3 even there it is not working. it says invalid login as soon as i enter my username and press enter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TTY doesn't wait for password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113704/tty-doesnt-wait-for-password)

Comment: @Nmath But i dont even if I  press enter. I press space bar to get the password screen. but as soon as i get the password prompt i see the error. i even tried creating a new user by going into root login via grub, but even there i am facing the same problem

Comment: I tried upgrading the kernel as suggested in the solution. it was Linux 4.18.0.20 i upgraded it to 4.18.0.21. still no difference..

Comment: This [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813873) was reportedly [fixed with kernel 4.18.0-15](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813873/comments/62) Have you tried a previous kernel? 4.18.0-15-generic from the repositories works fine here. Perhaps there has been a regression.

Answer (score 0):

@user3711432 when you hit space-bar to get the login screen it actually puts a space" " in the username field. Hit the backspace once or twice when you hit spacebar to get the login screen , and then type the username .
This will probably work