# 18.10 - "BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffffae4ca800"

Tags: kernel, 18.10

I've seen this error a few times in the last week. It sounds like a kernel problem to me.

Googling it gives a few hits, but nothing specific for a fix, other than possible new kernel fixes. AU has some hits, but also no specific fixes that I've seen.

It locks up the machine. I only have 4 or so apps running... Firefox, Thunderbird, Liferea, and KeePass. It just happened when I tried to restart the computer.

Anybody have any idea what this is about?

Comment: Do you use safely remove of USB 3.0 storage. Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1099414/66509) look as your issue?

Comment: @N0rbert thanks for the link. Funny enough, I remove USB 3.0 drives same as you... safely remove, then power off. But... that's not my problem in this case. The kernel paging error seems to occur randomly. I just updated to the 4.18.0-14-generic kernel, and removed r8168-dkms which was throwing a PKCS#7 error at boot time. We'll see how it goes. Cheers!

Comment: So far, no errors with kernel 4.18.0-15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to improve with kernels 4.18.0-15/16/17. However, since upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04 with kernel 5.0.0.-13, I haven't seen this problem again so far.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar thing with 4.15.0-151-generic. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.. Makes me wonder if it is my hardware because it has never occurred before and started occurring randomly (once a day) just recently.

Comment: @Valentas Please start a new question, and include `ls -al /boot` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard. I'm hearing some things about -151. Boot to the prior kernel and see if that helps. Thanks!