# VirtualBox 6.0 problem in 14-04 LTS

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBox 6.0 runs fine up to and including kernel versions 4.4.0-142 but versions 143 and 144 broke it. The vboxdrv kernel module does not get installed and I can't work around it by creating a "fake" /dev/vboxdrv. 
How can I fix this. I'm still running kernel wersion 142.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox error after last (Ubuntu) Software Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126591/virtualbox-error-after-last-ubuntu-software-update) - consider to downgrade pin/lock kernel version or downgrade it to 4.4.0-138 . Change the commands inside my answer to the 14.04 related package names. See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1126693/66509).

Comment: I have backed down to kernel 142 and all works fine. Just wondered if others had same problem...Answer is yes so I hope developers are working on it for future kernal releases. Thanks to all for your support.

Comment: @N0rbert VTC and upvote!  **;-)**